# python: recursive dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, recursion

I need help with a pretty simple exercise I am trying to execute, just syntactically I'm a bit lost

basically I read in a very brief text file containing 15 lines of 3 elements (essentially 2 keys and a value)

put those elements into a dictionary comprised of dictionaries

the 1st dictionary contains location and the 2nd dictionary which is made up of the type of the item and how much it costs for example

```
gymnasium weights 15
market cereal 5    
gymnasium shoes 50   
saloon beer 3   
saloon whiskey 10   
market bread 5
```

which would result in this

```
{
  'gymnasium': {
     'weights': 15, 
     'shoes': 50
   }, 
   'saloon': {
      'beer': 3, 
      'whiskey': 10
   }
}
```

and so on for the other keys

basically I need to loop through this file but I'm struggling to read in the contents as a dict of dicts.

moreover without that portion i cant figure out how to append the inner list to the outer list if an instance of the key in the outer list occurs.

I would like to do this recursively

```
 location_dict = {} #row #name day weight temp
 item_dict = {}
 for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    location_dict[item_dict['location'] = item_dict`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution.

```
yourFile = open("yourFile.txt", "r")
yourText = yourFile.read()
textLines = yourText.split("\n")
locationDict = {}
for line in textLines:
    k1, k2, v = line.split(" ")
    if k1 not in locationDict.keys():
        locationDict[k1] = {}
    else:
        if k2 not in locationDict[k1].keys():
            locationDict[k1][k2] = int(v)
        else:
            locationDict[k1][k2] += int(v)

print locationDict
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey! I like you approach and it did help. Do you think you could address that second functionality I mentioned above regarding the addition of values for multiple instances of an item. still really stuck on this and its frustrating!

Comment: Hello there! I have just modified the answer to add the functionality you mention. It is worth to mention that I had to transform the value to integer using "int" to be able to make the arithmetical sum (otherwise the code would concatenate two strings). Does this work for you?

Answer (score 2):

this is a good use for setdefault (or defaultdict)

```
data = {}
for line in file:
    key1,key2,value = line.split()
    data.setdefault(key1,{})[key2] = value

print data
```

or based on your comment

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))

for line in file:
    key1,key2,value = line.split()
    data[key1][key2] += value

print data
```

Comment: *gymnasium weights 15 *gymnasium weights 20 
*market cereal 5    *market cereal 10 *market cereal 5
*gymnasium shoes 50   
*saloon beer 3   *saloon beer 7
*saloon whiskey 10   
*market bread 5. ========Thanks for your help! Just for logistical sake, how would you go about this situation where there are multiple instances of an item and I want to print in my end list, the total cost of all the values of the items that repeat. so market cereal: would print 'market':{ 'cereal: 20}, weights 35, etc, etc.

Comment: this methodology essentially appends the the value to the key? *i am looking to loop through the file, see if there's more than one instance of an item say {(beer: 10) (beer: 20) (beer: 15)}  I want the value of 45 to go into the data dict for the keys saloon: beer. Your original posting captures the original function perfectly, I was just wondering how to edit properly to add instances of values when the loop (or whatever) encounters said instances.